# Linq to XML and XPath nested descendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I'm having some troubles getting some child's returned from a LINQ-XML mixed with XPath queries. 
The main parent "Controller", has few fields, two of which have child's of their own.
Looks as follow:

```html
<Site>
  <Controllers>
    <Controller>
      <Name>CtrEast</Name>
      <CntrlType>xx1</CntrlType>
      <IPAddress>x.x.x.1</IPAddress>
      <NetworkId>123</NetworkId>
      <DeviceId>MyId</DeviceId>
      <IO>
        <Inputs>
          <Input>
          <Name>xyz_Temp</Name>
          <Channel>10</Channel>
          <Value>10.5</Value>
          </Input>
        </Inputs>
        <Outputs>
          <Output>
            <Name>xyz_vlv</Name>
            <Channel>8</Channel>
            <Value>20</Value>
          </Output>
        </Outputs>
      </IO>
      <ChildControllers>
        <ChildController>
          <Name>GF</Name>
          <CntrlType>xyz</CntrlType>
          <Id>850</Id>
          <Port>comm1</Port>
          <IO>
            <Inputs>
              <Input>
              <Name>GF_Temp</Name>
              <Channel>1</Channel>
              <Value>13.9</Value>
              </Input>
            </Inputs>
            <Outputs>
              <Output>
                <Name>xyz_vlv</Name>
                <Channel>8</Channel>
                <Value>20</Value>
              </Output>
            </Outputs>
          </IO>
        </ChildController>
      </ChildControllers>
    </Controller>
  </Controllers>
</Site>
```

I have no issues getting the child's from "Controller", as well as the child's from the "IO" element that belongs to the "Controller" element, and also I'm able to get the childs within the "ChildController". However, I'm not able to retrieve correctly the child's from the "IO" element, that belongs to the "ChildController".

The following is my LINQ XML and XPath code:

```js
NC_List =
                        (
                        from nc in XDocument.Load(@"Data.xml").Descendants("Controller")

                        let NC_Name = nc.Element("Name").Value
                        let NC_CntrlType = nc.Element("CntrlType").Value
                        let NC_IPAddress = nc.Element("IPAddress").Value
                        let NC_NetworkId = nc.Element("NetworkId").Value
                        let NC_DeviceId = nc.Element("DeviceId").Value
                        let NC_BacnetMSTPNetNum = nc.Element("BacnetMSTPNetNum").Value
                        let NC_BACnetDeviceId = nc.Element("BACnetDeviceId").Value
                        let NC_SerialNum = nc.Element("SerialNum").Value
                        let NC_VersionNum = nc.Element("VersionNum").Value

                        select new CtrlClass_NC
                        {
                            Name = NC_Name,
                            CntrlType = NC_CntrlType,
                            IPAddress = NC_IPAddress,
                            NetworkId = NC_NetworkId,
                            DeviceId = NC_DeviceId,
                            BacnetMSTPNetNum = NC_BacnetMSTPNetNum,
                            BACnetDeviceId = NC_BACnetDeviceId,
                            SerialNum = NC_SerialNum,
                            VersionNum = NC_VersionNum,

                            NC_IO =
                            (
                                from NC_io in nc.XPathSelectElements("IO/InfinityInputs/InfinityInput | IO/InfinityOutputs/InfinityOutput")
                                select new IO_Class
                                {
                                    IO_DeviceId = (string)NC_io.Element("DeviceId").Value,
                                    IO_Name = (string)NC_io.Element("Name").Value,
                                    IO_Channel = (string)NC_io.Element("Channel").Value,
                                    IO_Type = (string)NC_io.Element("Type").Value,
                                    IO_Value = (string)NC_io.Element("Value").Value,
                                    IO_Units = (string)NC_io.Element("Units").Value,
                                    IO_ElecType = (string)NC_io.Element("ElecType").Value,
                                    IO_Invert = (string)NC_io.Element("Invert").Value,
                                    IO_Conversion = (string)NC_io.Element("Conversion").Value,
                                    IO_Threshold = (string)NC_io.Element("Threshold").Value
                                }
                            ).ToList(),

                            Infinet =
                            (
                                from ic in nc.XPathSelectElements("InfinetControllers/InfinetController")
                        
                                let IC_Name = ic.Element("Name").Value
                                let IC_CntrlType = ic.Element("CntrlType").Value
                                let IC_InfinetId = ic.Element("InfinetId").Value
                                let IC_BACnetDeviceId = ic.Element("BACnetDeviceId").Value
                                let IC_Port = ic.Element("Port").Value
                                let IC_DeviceId = ic.Element("DeviceId").Value
                                let IC_NetworkId = ic.Element("NetworkId").Value
                                let IC_SerialNum = ic.Element("SerialNum").Value
                                let IC_VersionNum = ic.Element("VersionNum").Value

                                select new CtrlClass_IC
                                {
                                    Name = IC_Name,
                                    CntrlType = IC_CntrlType,
                                    InfinetId = IC_InfinetId,
                                    BACnetDeviceId = IC_BACnetDeviceId,
                                    Port = IC_Port,
                                    DeviceId = IC_DeviceId,
                                    NetworkId = IC_NetworkId,
                                    SerialNum = IC_SerialNum,
                                    VersionNum = IC_VersionNum,

                                    IC_IO =
                                    (
                                        from IC_io in nc.XPathSelectElements("InfinetControllers/InfinetController/IO/InfinityInputs/InfinityInput | InfinetControllers/InfinetController/IO/InfinityOutputs/InfinityOutput")                                        

                                        select new IO_Class
                                        {
                                            IO_DeviceId = (string)IC_io.Element("DeviceId").Value,
                                            IO_Name = (string)IC_io.Element("Name").Value,
                                            IO_Channel = (string)IC_io.Element("Channel").Value,
                                            IO_Type = (string)IC_io.Element("Type").Value,
                                            IO_Value = (string)IC_io.Element("Value").Value,
                                            IO_Units = (string)IC_io.Element("Units").Value,
                                            IO_ElecType = (string)IC_io.Element("ElecType").Value,
                                            IO_Invert = (string)IC_io.Element("Invert").Value,
                                            IO_Conversion = (string)IC_io.Element("Conversion").Value,
                                            IO_Threshold = (string)IC_io.Element("Threshold").Value
                                        }
                                    ).ToList(),
                                }
                            ).ToList()
                          }
                        ).ToList();
```

It is a valid query, and I'm able to get some values, however, what it doesn't make sense, is that for the IO from the "Controller" element, I get the right data, eg: 3 inputs and 4 outputs for the first controller, then something different for the next controller. For the "ChildController", is like all 200 ChildControllers have the same quantity of points and data within. I get like 419 inputs and outputs underneath each of the childcontroller/IO elements.

Hope it makes sense. I'm sure it must be something simple, but I can't see the problem within my code.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Regards,

Alain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the xml that you have provided and using XElement (note the IO section of child controllers and regular controllers can be factored out since it is common). And I also did not factor in missing elements and values (as you will see I use First().Value in some places).

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(GetXmlToProcess());
var Controllers = xml.Elements("Controllers").Select(x=> x)
                      .Elements("Controller").Select(x=> 
                      {
                          return GetControllerFromXml(x);
                      });


public Controller GetControllerFromXml( XElement elem)
{
    var controller  = new Controller();
    controller.Name = elem.Elements("Name").First().Value;
    controller.CntrlType = elem.Elements("CntrlType").First().Value;
    controller.IPAddress = elem.Elements("IPAddress").First().Value;
    controller.NetworkId = elem.Elements("NetworkId").First().Value;
    controller.DeviceId = elem.Elements("DeviceId").First().Value;
    var io = elem.Elements("IO");
    if (io != null)
    {
        controller.IO.Inputs.AddRange( io.Elements("Inputs")
                                        .Elements("Input")
                                        .Select(v=> new Input
                                                {
                                                    Name =  v.Elements("Name").First().Value,
                                                    Channel =  v.Elements("Channel").First().Value,
                                                    Value =  v.Elements("Value").First().Value
                                                })
                                    );
        controller.IO.Outputs.AddRange( io.Elements("Outputs")
                                        .Elements("Output")
                                        .Select(v=> new Output
                                                {
                                                    Name =  v.Elements("Name").First().Value,
                                                    Channel =  v.Elements("Channel").First().Value,
                                                    Value =  v.Elements("Value").First().Value
                                                })
                                    );
    }
    var childrenController =  elem.Elements("ChildControllers");
    if(childrenController != null)
    {
        foreach(var child in childrenController.Elements("ChildController"))
        {
            var childController =  new ChildController();
            controller.ChildControllers.Add(childController);
            childController.Name = child.Elements("Name").First().Value;
            childController.CntrlType = child.Elements("CntrlType").First().Value;
            childController.Id = child.Elements("Id").First().Value;
            childController.Port = child.Elements("Port").First().Value;
            var cio = child.Elements("IO");
            if (cio != null)
            {
                childController.IO.Inputs.AddRange( cio.Elements("Inputs")
                                        .Elements("Input")
                                        .Select(v=> new Input
                                                {
                                                    Name =  v.Elements("Name").First().Value,
                                                    Channel =  v.Elements("Channel").First().Value,
                                                    Value =  v.Elements("Value").First().Value
                                                })
                                    );
                childController.IO.Outputs.AddRange( cio.Elements("Outputs")
                                        .Elements("Output")
                                        .Select(v=> new Output
                                                {
                                                    Name =  v.Elements("Name").First().Value,
                                                    Channel =  v.Elements("Channel").First().Value,
                                                    Value =  v.Elements("Value").First().Value
                                                })
                                    );
    }

        }
    }

    return controller;
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Controller
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string CntrlType{get; set;}
    public string IPAddress{get; set;}
    public string NetworkId{get; set;}
    public string DeviceId{get; set;}
    public IO IO {get;set;}
    public List<ChildController> ChildControllers{get; set;}

    public Controller()
    {
        IO  = new IO();
        ChildControllers = new List<ChildController>();
    }
}

public class ChildController
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string CntrlType{get; set;}
    public string Id{get; set;}
    public string Port{get; set;}
    public IO IO {get;set;}

    public ChildController()
    {
        IO  = new IO();
    }
}

public class IO
{
    public List<Input> Inputs {get; set;} 
    public List<Output> Outputs  {get; set;} 
    public IO()
    {
        Inputs = new List<Input>();
        Outputs = new List<Output>();
    }
}
public class Input
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Channel{get; set;}
    public string Value{get; set;}
}

public class Output
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Channel{get; set;}
    public string Value{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi TYY, thank you so much for your answer. Not only works better, but you also got me thinking that I should stop using XPath all together. Your solution and approach to it, is great. Thanks again for taking the time to do it. 10/10 :)

Comment: No worries, just make sure you watch out for the First().Value that I use here, you should probably do a firstOrDefault and check for NULL.

Comment: Thanks TYY. Any good tutorials that you may recommend, for detail use and implementation of X Element with custom classes?